# How do I fix dependency and tar problems with linux-image-extra* package?

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, software-center, dpkg

Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Trusty Tahr
`linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic_3.13.0-49.56` is current package

The Ubuntu Software Updater is set to check for updates daily. The last set of updates included `linux-image-extras*`. However, `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic_3.13.0-49.81_i386.deb` could not be installed, owing first to a tar unpack problem and second to unresolved dependencies.

Ubuntu Software Centre produced this output (in part):

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ...     
(Reading database ... 5%  
...  
(Reading database ... 100%  
(Reading database ... 523867 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic_3.13.0-49.81_i386.deb ...  
Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic (3.13.0-49.81) ...  
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic_3.13.0-49.81_i386.deb (--unpack):  
 corrupted filesystem tarfile - corrupted package archive
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic_3.13.0-49.81_i386.deb  
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:  
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic; however:  
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic is not installed.  

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):  
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

After looking through apparently similar questions, I tried some of the suggested solutions:

```
$ sudo apt-get clean  
$ sudo apt-get autoremove  
$ sudo apt-get -f install  
$ sudo apt-get update  
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I am somewhat hampered in pursuing further solutions because after the above attempts, *connection to my wifi router was lost* and I can't restore it. The cordless *mouse also stopped working*, and the *display is too wide* (behaving as though the aspect ratio is 16:9, instead of the 4:3 it actually is). The system preferences are correct for all these problems, so possibly some drivers have gone AWOL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic_3.13.0-49.81_i386.deb` not being updated over the previous release was caused by the package being damaged in some way when Ubuntu Software Centre, Synaptic, or apt-get downloaded it.

Go to the temporary download folder ...

```
 gksudo nautilus /var/cache/apt/archives
```

... and delete the package `.deb` file. Now rerun the update in the package manager of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

The problems with the *connection to my wifi router being lost* and being unable to restore it, the *cordless mouse note working*, and the *display being too wide* would have taken days to debug and fix manually. Search in askubuntu for the many questions related to these issues, in my case probably stemming from the `linux-image-extras*` package.

Take the easy way out and reinstall your current release of Ubuntu without damaging your data:

1. Back up your home directory (`~/`),
2. Download the latest *.iso image and burn an installation DVD, and
3. Boot off the DVD and choose Install at the startup page.

See

- Preview a normal installation at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop (Install Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS)
- Overview of reinstalling at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation (How To Reinstall Ubuntu)
- Detailed instructions for reinstalling http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2057342 (How to re-install Ubuntu keeping your data and settings)